# For GCP Composer, How to delete a DAG with "gcloud" command in GCP Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I want to run a "gcloud" command:

`gcloud composer environments run --location us-central1 my-composer-instance delete_dag -- my_dag_id`

Inside a Compute Instance. What's the best way to do it?

So far, running the "delete_dag" command will return this error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) Invalid choice: 'delete_dag'.
> Did you mean 'list_dags'?

Then if I run the "list_dags" command, it will ask me to install `kubectl` with:

`$ gcloud components install kubectl`

But when I install `kubectl`:

> ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is managed by an external package manager.
> Please consider using a separate installation of the Cloud SDK created through the default mechanism described at: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Answer (score 1):

You need to installing [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) in to the VM instance to execute the command. To delete a DAG you need to remove the Python .py file for the DAG from the environment's dags folder in Cloud Storage. To removing a DAG you can follow the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#deleting_a_dag).

```
gcloud composer environments storage dags delete \
    --environment ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location LOCATION \
    DAG_NAME.py
```

Or ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/run))

```
gcloud composer environments run --location LOCATION ENVIRONMENT_NAME delete_dag --DAG_NAME
```

where:
`ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is the name of the environment.
`LOCATION` is the Compute Engine region where the environment is located.
`DAG_NAME` is the name of the DAG to delete.

Comment: Hi @Mahboob and Ksign, thank you for your comment. I can already remove the .py file from the dag folder (GCS Bucket). But in order to remove the dag from [GCP's Airflow web interface](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#delete-md) I need to run the above command you provided. The problem is I don't think Compute Instance lets me "delete" dags. (I will update my question with an error message)

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt install kubectl` instead of `gcloud components install kubectl` solved my problem.